# Most efficient way for finding 3 rows with maximum value in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, processing-efficiency

Lets us say there is a dataframe **df**

```
Name  Balance
A     1000
B     5000
C     3000
D     6000
E     2000
F     5000
```

I am looking for an approach through which I can get three rows with highest balances among all.

```
df['balance'].get_indices_max(n=3) # where is no. of results required
```

Output when these indices will be used to get rows:

```
D 6000
F 5000
B 5000
```

UPDATE : EXTRA NOTES REGARDING THE ACCEPTED ANSWER

Possible "keep" values -

```
first : prioritize the first occurrence(s)

last : prioritize the last occurrence(s)

all : do not drop any duplicates, even it means selecting more than n items.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

```py
df = Df({"Name":list("ABCDEF"), "Balance":[1000,5000,3000,6000,2000,5000]})
index = df["Balance"].nlargest(3).index
df.loc[index]
```

### Output

```
  Name  Balance
3    D     6000
1    B     5000
5    F     5000
```

### Attantion

1. Performant

> The columns that are not specified are returned as well, but not used for ordering.
> This method is equivalent to df.sort_values(columns, ascending=False).head(n), but more performant.

2. `nlargest(3, keep='all')`

> keep{‘first’, ‘last’, ‘all’}, default ‘first’
>
> When using keep='all', all duplicate items are maintained

Example

```py
df = Df({"Name":list("ABCDEFX"), "Balance":[1000,5000,3000,6000,2000,5000,5000]})
index = df["Balance"].nlargest(3, keep='all').index
df.loc[index]
```

```
  Name  Balance
3    D     6000
1    B     5000
5    F     5000
6    X     5000
```

### Reference

- [DataFrame.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

Comment: If we don't specify the "keep" parameter of nlargest function then it will default to "first" mode which will drop duplicates and the two balances with the same amount will not get printed. Should you mention to use "keep = all" ?

Comment: @DevasyaDave good idea

Answer (score 1):

I usual do

```
out = df.sort_values('Balance').iloc[3:]
Out[476]: 
  Name  Balance
1    B     5000
5    F     5000
3    D     6000
```

Comment: Fully sorting an array to get only 3 values is not efficient when the target array is big. This solution will likely uses an `O(n log n)` algorithm internally while the one of @FavorMylikes uses should use a partition algorithm internally running in `O(n)` time.

Comment: I agree with Jerome Richard. That is the reason I was not going ahead with this approach. The function nlargest by@FavorMylikes is mentioned as more performant in the documentation.